# Intermittent AKMIDISampler crash

Tags: swift, xcode, crash, midi, audiokit

This project uses several AKMIDISamplers in a playback loop during which pitches and audio file are frequently changed. Everything works like a charm. Yet after what seems to be complete random intervals (minutes) Xcode drops into the debugger with:

```
Thread 13: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

function signature specialization <Arg[1] = Dead> of AudioKit.AKMIDIEvent.init(packet: __C.MIDIPacket) -> AudioKit.AKMIDIEvent

0 specialized AKMIDIEvent.init(packet:)
1 specialized closure #1 in AKMIDISampler.enableMIDI(_:name:)
```

Here is the initialization code:

```
let sampler = AKMIDISampler()
  do {
    if let audioFile = try AKAudioFile(readFileName: filePath) as AKAudioFile! {
      try sampler.loadAudioFile(audioFile)
    }
  } catch { print("audio file error: \(error)") }
```

AKMIDISampler's MIDI functionality is not being used, i.e. not listening to MIDI events or sending any. The only way to intentionally cause this crash is by halting the sequencer the AKMIDISampler is attached to for a while. This is AudioKit 4.0.4.

Comment: me too: did you find a solution?

Comment: No, but check: https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/issues/1259